# How to get specific member username with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to add one specific member information (username + avatar) into an embed message. Does someone know how to do that?

```
const feedback = new discord.RichEmbed()
.setColor([0, 0, 255])
.setFooter("Bot created by : " + message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
.setDescription("The text I want to be sent")
```

On the code above, I would like to change "message.author.username" and "message.author.avatarUrl" by a specific discord member identification id such as : 436577130583949315 for example.

However I don't know what is the way from that discord identification number to be able to show the username and the avatar.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The following code must be modified to use the latest version of Discord.js (v12 at the time of this edit) due to the implementation of Managers.*

---

You can retrieve a user by their ID from the client's cache of users, [`Client#users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Client?scrollTo=users). However, every user isn't guaranteed to be cached at all times, so you can fetch a user from Discord using [`Client#fetchUser()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Client?scrollTo=fetchUser). Keep in mind, it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). If the user *is* in the cache, the method will return it.

Example:

```js
// Async context needed for 'await'

try {
  const devID = '436577130583949315';
  const dev = await client.fetchUser(devID);

  const feedback = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor([0, 0, 255])
    .setFooter(`Bot created by ${dev.tag}.`, dev.displayAvatarURL)
    .setDescription('Your text here.');

  await message.channel.send(feedback);
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much