# Is there a Client.fetchUser() equivalent in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to find a way to get a User object from a user's ID alone. `Client#fetchUser()` seemed to be what I was looking for, referring to this 
[older question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619167/how-to-get-specific-member-username-with-discord-js)

However that function is no longer in the [Discord.js Client Object Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)

And I can't seem to find a way of doing what `fetchUser()` is supposed to do. I need to create User Object from User IDs because I'm retrieving saved user data and need to be able to send messages to the users I'm retrieving from save data.

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they merged the functionality of [UserManager#fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch)

into what I was looking for, in which it is described as

```
Obtains a user from Discord, or the user cache if it's already available.

PARAMETER   TYPE    OPTIONAL    DEFAULT DESCRIPTION
id  Snowflake           
ID of the user

cache   boolean     true    
Whether to cache the new user object if it isn't already

Returns: Promise<User>
```

So it'll either grab the user from the cache by ID, or retrieve it from Discord if it's not in the cache. I'm guessing they did this to make this functionality more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to go about doing this:

Getting the user from the `client.users.cache` collection

```js
const user = client.users.cache.get(UserID)
```

Fetching the user using the `fetch()` method in the `UserManager` of `client.users`

```js
const user = client.users.fetch(UserID)
```

Comment: client.users.fetch(id) returns the user object, but I can't access any of the values

Comment: @IanSwift create a question with your code, error, intended function.